# How to switch twitter-feed data-theme to dark/light mode using jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-feed

I want to switch the twitter feed to dark/light mode when clicking on the buttons.
It tried to add using jquery but it is not working for me.

```js
function lighttheme() {
  $('#twitterfeeds').attr('data-theme', 'light');
  $('#twitterfeeds').prop('data-theme', 'light');
}

function darktheme() {
  $('#twitterfeeds').attr('data-theme', 'dark');
  $('#twitterfeeds').prop('data-theme', 'dark');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center pb-2">
  <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="darktheme()">Dark</button>
  <button class="btn btn-light" onclick="lighttheme()">Light</button>
</div>



<div>
  <a class="twitter-timeline twitterfeeds" data-theme="dark" id="twitterfeeds" href="https://twitter.com/ForexLive?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by ForexLive</a>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, use unobtrusive event handlers, not inline ones. Secondly, does the theme of whatever library you're using really change based on the `data` attribute? That seems unlikely.

Comment: I took the twitter feeds from twitter website.

Comment: Also, I am new to jquery. so Plz guide me. I don't understand what you are talking about.